# Why does "a or b or c" not work with NumPy arrays?

Tags: python

I would like  to assign to `d` either `a` or, if `a` is `None`, `b` or, if `b` is also `None`, `c`. This works:

```
a = b = c = np.array([1])
d = a or b or c
```

However, this does not:

```
a = b = c = np.array([1, 2])
d = a or b or c
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Apparently, or is being used element-wise for arrays with more than one element. What can I do to achieve

```
d = a or b or c
```

with NumPy arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to assign to `d` either `a` or, if `a` is `None`, `b` or, if `b` is also `None`, `c`.

Then literally check for `None`:

```
d = a if a is not None else b if b is not None else c
```

The fact that your version works for single-element arrays is a side-effect of their truthiness. It won't do what you expect with this:

```
a = np.array([0])
b = "wat"

c = a or b
```

`c` will now be `"wat"`, even though `a` is not `None`.

Comment: The `np.array([0])` case is pretty convincing.

Comment: If you have a ton of these and my solution becomes unwieldy, you can do `import itertools; first_not_none = next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x is None, [some list of possibly None-y things]))`.